# Codeigniter function image_lib->crop() not working..!

Tags: codeigniter

I have tried to crop image by using the library function of codeigniter. But $this->image_lib->crop() function couldn't change the image.

Here is my code-

```
    <?php

    class Cropimg extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg';
    $config['x_axis'] = '300';
    $config['y_axis'] = '200';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['new_image'] = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\new_crop_img.jpg';
   // $config['width'] = $width-10;
    //$config['height'] = $height-10;


    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 


    if ( ! $this->image_lib->crop())

   echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    else
     echo "<strong>Your image has been cropped successfully..!!</strong>";
}
   }
```

?>

Comment: does it report any errors?

Comment: Have you tried a filepath with no spaces?

Comment: Try this C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg & C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\new_crop_img.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code its working fine. **Do you get any errors while cropping?**

```
    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg';
    $config['new_image'] = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\new_crop_img.jpg';
    $config['height'] = '200';
    $config['width'] = '300';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->image_lib->crop())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }else
    {
        echo "<strong>Your image has been cropped successfully..!!</strong>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide height as well as width for this.
Height & width is necessary to tell  that from a point(X-axis, Y-axis) what will be length of image towards right side & what will be length (as a height) towards downside. These will be considered as height & width of that image.

So un-comment

```
 $config['height'] = '200';
 $config['width'] = '300';
```